# what SupersetAdmin is doing?

Tags: apache-superset

In superset action log, there are many SupsersetAdmin logs.
What does the user SupersetAdmin do?

User SupersetAdmin has a problem with using Google Big Query scan volume

Could not find what user SupersetAdmin is doing in superset documentation.